# How to call a Managed DLL File in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, call, external, managed

I am making a scripting language but I have  a serious problem.

I need to make it so you can call .NET DLLs in the language but I have found no way to do this in C#.

Does any one know how can I load and call a .NET dll programmatically? (I can not just Add reference so don't say that)

Comment: Why does adding a reference not work?

Comment: Because I it is for a scripting language , the user needs to be able to call any DLL that is placed in the same directory as the interrupter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
System.Type type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
IYourType yourObj = (o as IYourType);
```

where `assemblyName` and `typeName` are strings, for example:

```
string assemblyName = @"C:\foo\yourDLL.dll";
string typeName = "YourCompany.YourProject.YourClass";//a fully qualified type name
```

then you can call methods on your obj:

```
yourObj.DoSomething(someParameter);
```

Of course, what methods you can call is defined by your interface `IYourType`...

Comment: It's sometimes a good idea to create a separate app domain for the loaded assembly which means you can throw it away once you're done.

Comment: How did you reference `IYourType` without referencing the DLL in the project?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx), from there use standard [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx) to get at types and methods (i assume you already do this in your scripting). The example on the MSDN page (linked) shows this:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
// Obtain a reference to a method known to exist in assembly.
MethodInfo Method = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0].GetMethod("Method1");
// Obtain a reference to the parameters collection of the MethodInfo instance.
ParameterInfo[] Params = Method.GetParameters();
// Display information about method parameters.
// Param = sParam1
//   Type = System.String
//   Position = 0
//   Optional=False
foreach (ParameterInfo Param in Params)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Param=" + Param.Name.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Type=" + Param.ParameterType.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Position=" + Param.Position.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  Optional=" + Param.IsOptional.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to use one of the overloads of Assembly.Load ([Assembly.Load at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx)). Once you have dynamically loaded your assembly, you can use System.Reflection, dynamic objects, and/or interfaces/base classes to access types within it.