# ASP.net LoadAssembly dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I'm trying to load an assembly at runtime.
For that I'm using the following line:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(file.FullName);
```

file is a FileInfo object, so file.FullName returns the full path to the file on the filesystem, e.g.: c:\mywebsite\dlls\myassembly.dll

When I try to execute the line above I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'c:\mywebsite\dlls\myassembly.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I'm sure this isn't a dependency problem, and I don't know what's an "invalid codebase"

Note that if I put the assembly directly on the BIN folder of the site everything works correctly, I just can't make load dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To supplement Schroedingers Cat's answer, you might want to look at [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) if you only have the file path. But you might get security issues when running from ASP.NET which may require configuring permissions on the file system, to allow your website to access the file.

Comment: This question is answered, but the site still says it can't find a type that's inside the assembly that was dynamically loaded.
How can I load this assembly to be used as if it is on the Bin folder?

Comment: It blows right on the first line of the ASCX:

<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Entity1Item.ascx.cs" Inherits="App.Modules.ModuleA.Controls.Entity1Item" %>


Could not load type 'App.Modules.ModuleA.Controls.Entity1Item'.

Comment: It loads the ascx markup but can't find the type that's defined on the dll. If I add the dll to the bin of the website it works correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "long form of the assembly name" not the file path to the code:
[see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a security/permissions issue - you can't load assemblies from outside bin without the proper permissions (depending on the account used to run)...

Comment: I thought about this and to get this issue out of the way I gave my admin account to the app pool that this website is running on. So this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to permissions, generally an asp.net website is not going to have access (particularly execute access) to files outside it's root directory.

Answer (score 0):

That method expects the assembly name. What you want is [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx), although you will have to be carefull with permissions as you're calling this from an [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) app.

See here for more info: [How to call a Managed DLL File in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830610/how-to-call-a-managed-dll-file-in-c)