# C# Bi Directional function call from / to DLL

Tags: c#, dllimport

I know how to call a DLL function from main assembly, 
but would also like to call the main c# assembly function from the DLL function.
What is the best way to achieve this ? any idea ?

Comment: I think you have a problem of code design here. If your 'main assembly' is to be called from a library, then the functions in the main assembly that need to be called should also be in (another) library.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891752/c-sharp-using-assembly-to-call-a-method-within-a-dll

Comment: The Main assembly is a generic code and the DLL is a project specific code

Comment: This makes no sense at all and creates a circular dependency. It sounds like you should move some code from one assembly into another. Anyway without any code it´s impossible to guess how to solve your issue.

Comment: A little more context would help here.

Comment: Can the main program pass in a delegate/reference to the function that the DLL assembly needs to call?

Comment: Yes , i can pass a delegate/reference to the function that the DLL assembly